# Comparing ranked results to itself to affix it with a '=' if equal

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create some SQL that says if the rank of a column is the same to affix it with a '='

I've tried using a case statement to find the same result, but obviously this is just finding the same column and always comes away as true.

Code to give me the rank that is stored in a temp table.

```
 RANK ( ) OVER ( partition by ac.line_id order by cast(stm.mark as int) DESC) ,
 COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ac.line_id) as total_mark_rank,
```

I was playing around with the below in my final query.

```
SELECT 

CASE 
WHEN 
wsa.total_mark_rank= wsa.total_mark_rank
THEN  '=' + wsa.total_mark_rank
 ELSE wsa.total_mark_rank end

from wsa
```

I expect that is two people have a rank of '1' they will both show as '=1'. currently with my query they all show as '=1'

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us the **complete** SQL query you are using. And please tell us which database product you are using (`'=' + wsa.total_mark_rank` is invalid standard SQL)

Answer (score 0):

I have used `person_id` as the identifier for who the mark belongs to.

You could use a self join. It simply looks for another `person_id` with the same `total_mark_rank` & prepends an equals sign to the rank if there is. If not, it just takes the rank as is.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  wsa.person_id,
                 CASE WHEN wsa2.total_mark_rank IS NULL
                      THEN CAST(wsa.total_mark_rank AS VARCHAR(4))
                      ELSE '=' + CAST(wsa2.total_mark_rank AS VARCHAR(4))
                 END As rank_position
FROM   wsa
       LEFT JOIN wsa wsa2 ON wsa2.total_mark_rank = wsa.total_mark_rank
                             AND wsa2.person_id <> wsa.person_id
```